# Is there a way to have an Azure Pipeline only build specific projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-pipelines, csproj

I have an Azure Pipeline that builds all the projects within a solution, but I want to pick and choose which projects get built or ignored by the pipeline. I think that having a "ToBuildBool" boolean to flag which projects are to be built or not is the way to go. The "ToBuildBool" is set as "true" by default and can be set to "false" manually in the csproj files of the projects I do not want built by the pipeline, but rather to be ignored. Am I on the right track? How do I set the boolean flag in a csproj file?

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'DotNetCore Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom' 
    custom: 'build'
    projects: 'MySolution.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    arguments: '-c Release -p:ToBuildBool=true'   # set build flag'
```

Comment: You can include and exclude whatever projects you like, in your [solution file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022); is there a reason you don't want to do it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple projects to the `projects` parameter. That's why it's plural, not singular. Refer to the documentation for the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task for examples of supported patterns.

Or you can have multiple sequential invocations of the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, one per project you'd like to build.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. However, my solution has over one hundred projects and listing each one of them would be quite wordy. Is there a way to do this with the bool flag method I mentioned?

Comment: You can also specify **exclusions**, so you can build everything *except* a subset. Or you can create a solution that contains just the subset of projects you want to build. There are a lot of options, but messing around in MSBuild is probably not a good one.